# Understanding matrix equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If I have two matrices

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        0 & -3 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$,   $ AX = \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -2 \\
        1 & -1 \\
        3 & -3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} = B$

how can this be [A|B] ~ [I|X]? I don't understand the logistics behind it. I understand that $AA^{-1} = I$ but I don't know how to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is what you stated:
$$
AX=B\Rightarrow A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}B\Rightarrow(A^{-1}A)X=A^{-1}B,
$$
hence:
$$
X=A^{-1}B.
$$